# Why different local size in OpenCL gives different result?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to perform a basic matrix multiplication algorithm using OpenCL. Both matrices are supposed to have equal dimensions (SIZE x SIZE), so I defined the problem as a bidimensional one, with global size SIZE x SIZE, and I'm testing what happens with different local sizes.

The kernel is writen as follows:

```
__kernel void matmul(
    __global unsigned int *a,
    __global unsigned int *b,
    __global unsigned int *c
) {
    int row, col, i, size;
    unsigned int dot;

    row = get_global_id(0);
    col = get_global_id(1);
    size = get_global_size(0);

    dot = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dot += a[row * size + i] * b[i * size + col];
    }

    c[row * size + col] = dot;
}
```

It works nice if global and local sizes are set to 1024 x 1024 and 1 x 1, respectively. However, it turns out that if the local size is 2 x 2 or 4 x 4, I get wrong results in the multiplication. Now, for local size using multiples of 8, like 8 x 8, 16 x 16, ... There is no error in the multiplication. Why is that happening?

I don't know if the problem is in the programming of the kernel, or it is that I have a bad understanding on what can be done with a work-group or work-item.

The complete host code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>

#define SIZE (1024)
#define WORKITEMS (4096)
#define LOG_SIZE (2048)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j, k, size, errors;

    // Host memory
    cl_uint *a_host = NULL;
    cl_uint *b_host = NULL;
    cl_uint *c_host = NULL;
    cl_uint ref_dot;

    // Device memory
    cl_mem a_device;
    cl_mem b_device;
    cl_mem c_device;

    // Performance measurements
    struct timeval t0, tf;
    float ts, tp, tb;

    // OpenCL variables
    FILE *f;
    size_t f_size;
    size_t global[3] = {0}, local[3] = {0};
    char *buffer = NULL;
    cl_int ret;
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;

    // [1] Initialize application

    // Read command line arguments to configure run
    size = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : SIZE;
    printf("Matrix multiplication with OpenCL (Size = %d)\n", size);

    // Allocate memory for host variables
    a_host = malloc(size * size * sizeof *a_host);
    b_host = malloc(size * size * sizeof *b_host);
    c_host = malloc(size * size * sizeof *c_host);

    // Initialize input arrays
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            a_host[i * size + j] = rand();
            b_host[i * size + j] = rand();
        }
    }

    // [2] Initialize OpenCL environment

    // Get platform
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    // Get device
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device, NULL);

    // Create context
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create command queue
    queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device, 0, &ret);

    // [3] Compile OpenCL kernel
    f = fopen("kernel.cl", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    f_size = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    // Read file into memory
    buffer = malloc(f_size + 1);
    buffer[f_size] = '\0';
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), f_size, f);
    fclose(f);

    // Create program
    printf("<OpenCL> Kernel source:\n%s", buffer);
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &buffer, &f_size, &ret);

    // Build program
    printf("<OpenCL> Building kernel...\n");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, "-cl-std=CL2.0", NULL, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&tf, NULL);
    tb = ((tf.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0) + ((tf.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0);
    printf("Build time: %.3f ms\n", tb);

    // Print build log (optional)
    char log[LOG_SIZE];
    ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, LOG_SIZE, log, NULL);
    printf("<OpenCL> Kernel build log:\n%s\n", log);

    // [4] Configure OpenCL kernel

    // Create kernel
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "matmul", &ret);

    // Create device buffers
    a_device = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size * size * sizeof *a_host, NULL, &ret);
    b_device = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size * size * sizeof *b_host, NULL, &ret);
    c_device = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, size * size * sizeof *c_host, NULL, &ret);

    // Set kernel parameters
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_device);
    ret |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &b_device);
    ret |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_device);

    // [5] Execute kernel
    printf("<OpenCL> Executing kernel...\n");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);

    // Write data from host to device
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, a_device, CL_TRUE, 0, size * size * sizeof *a_host, a_host, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, b_device, CL_TRUE, 0, size * size * sizeof *b_host, b_host, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Enqueue kernel for execution
    global[0] = size;
    global[1] = size;
    local[0] = 2;
    local[1] = 2;
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global, local, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Wait for kernel to finish
    ret = clFinish(queue);

    // Read data from device to host
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, c_device, CL_TRUE, 0, size * size * sizeof *c_host, c_host, 0, NULL, NULL);

    gettimeofday(&tf, NULL);
    tp = ((tf.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0) + ((tf.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0);
    printf("[PAR] Execution time: %.3f ms\n", tp);

    // [6] Print results, perform checks

    // Compute golden reference and check errors

    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    errors = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            ref_dot = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                ref_dot += a_host[i * size + k] * b_host[k * size + j];
            }

            if (ref_dot != c_host[i * size + j]) {
                errors++;
            }
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&tf, NULL);
    ts = ((tf.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0) + ((tf.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0);
    printf("[SEQ] Execution time : %.3f ms\n", ts);
    printf("Found %d error%s\n", errors, (errors == 1) ? "" : "s");

    // [7] Cleanup system

    // Cleanup host variables
    free(a_host);
    free(b_host);
    free(c_host);
    free(buffer);

    // Cleanup OpenCL
    clReleaseMemObject(a_device);
    clReleaseMemObject(b_device);
    clReleaseMemObject(c_device);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The global range has to be an exact multiple of the local range. If this is not the case, the GPU may read from or write to an undefined memory region (if not explicitly caught in the kernel with an `if(rwo>=SIZE||col>SIZE) return;`* in the beginning of the kernel before any memory loads/stores).
* This is branching should be avoided for performance reasons.

GPU threads operate in groups of `32` (warps), so the local range should be at least `32` or a multiple thereof. If the local range is for example only `16`, then half of each warp will idle, halving the available processing power. The minimum size that works for you is `8x8=64 > 32`.

Example in 1D:

- global range `64`, local range `32`: thread block 1 does items `0-31`, thread block 2 does items `32-63`. Everything works properly.
- global range `64`, local range `40`: thread block 1 does items `0-39`, thread block 2 does items `40-79`. Thread block 2 operates in an undefined memory region with items 64-79. The compiler will not warn you, but you will eventually see incorrect results.

Similarly to the second example, I suspect some of the remaining threads of a warp operate in an undefined memory region when your local range is smaller than `32`, for example with the local range `4x4=16 < 32`.